# Sort posts with multiple meta_keys

Tags: query-posts

does anybody know how to filter post by meta_key1 (meta_key1=something) and order by meta_key2 at the same time ?

`query_posts('post_type=press_articles&posts_per_page=5&meta_key=dt_featured_press_radio&meta_value=yes&order=ASC')`
how add order by meta_key2 here ? 
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) supports multiple values for the `orderby` argument (see the example from that link on the Codex.

I don't know if `query_posts()` does as well, but I suspect the `pre_get_posts` filter does, in which case you can replace `query_posts()` with that (which is the new "best practice" anyway).